# Hide user control present in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, hide, master-pages

I have an user control in master page with id 'ucTopUser' and a button 'btnSub'.I need to hide the both control from my current aspx page.How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the Masterpage from your aspx page you can use `this.Master`, and to hide the elements you can set their `Visible` property to `false`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx

```
((UserControl)this.Master.FindControl("ucTopUser")).Visible = false;
((Button)this.Master.FindControl("btnSub")).Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use jQuery. Just add `$("#ucTopUser").hide(); $("#btnSub").hide();` to your $(document).ready() function.